# What conditions must $X$ fulfill for conditional expectation $\mathbb {E} [X|\mathcal{B} ]$ to exist?

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and 
$$
X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
$$ 
is a real-valued random variable.

Let $\mathcal{B}$ a sub-$\sigma $ algebra of $\mathcal{F} $.

What conditions must $X$ fulfill for conditional expectation $\mathbb {E} [X|\mathcal{B} ]$ to exist ?

Comment: Only $\mathbb E|X|<\infty$.

Comment: but if $X^+$ or $X^- $ is integrable. Can we say that $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{B} ]$ exists?

Comment: If you admit extended random variables (with possible infinite values) then you can consider the case when only $X^+$ or $X^-$ are integrable. And then define $E(X|\mathcal F)=E(X^+|\mathcal F)-E(X^-|\mathcal F)$. This cases are discussed in the book Probability, 2nd edn. Albert N, Shiryaev, Springer‐Verlag, Berlin, 1994, chapter II, paragraph 7.